# Django Rest Framework Filter not Working, The filter button is not showing on browsable API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

Good day I am new with django and django rest framework. I am trying to do some filtering. I followed the steps on the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/ but nothing is working, it doesnt even show the filter button on browsable api. hope someone can help. thank you

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'rfproducts',
    'frontend'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 15,
}
```

views.py

```
class ProductsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializers
    filterset_fields = ['category']
```

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_partnumber = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_link = models.URLField()
    pdf_link = models.URLField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    specifications = ProductSpecificationSerializers(many=True)
    manufacturer_details = ManufacturerSerializers(source='manufacturer', read_only=True)
    category_details = CategorySerializers(source='category', read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ['id', 'product_partnumber', 'image_link', 'pdf_link', 'manufacturer', 'manufacturer_details', 'category', 'category_details', 'subcategory', 'specifications']

    def create(self, request):
        specs_data = request.pop('specifications')
        product = Products.objects.create(**request)
        
        for spec_data in specs_data:
            ProductSpecification.objects.create(product=product, **spec_data)

        return product
```

when I try to access some parameters in the url like

```
api/products?category=2
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .api import ProductsView, ManufacturerView, SpecificationView, CategoryView, SubcategoryView
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/products', ProductsView, 'products' )
router.register('api/manufacturers', ManufacturerView, 'manufacturers')
router.register('api/specifications', SpecificationView, 'specification')
router.register('api/category', CategoryView, 'category')
router.register('api/subcategory', SubcategoryView, 'subcategory')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

it retruns a blank page with status 200 response. Category field cointains a foreign key.

I am using react for my frontend, does it affect the issue?

In the image the filter button is not showing on the browsable API and also the category value in the url parameters is also existing

[sample broswsable api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plBKn.png)

Comment: Where is your code snippet? Show what you have tried

Comment: @ArakkalAbu already edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: *"it returns a blank page with status 200 response"*, seems like the filter is working. Probably, there is no `category` with PK `2`

Comment: I only have small of data for testing and I am sure that there is a PK value of 2 on my category field. Also when I access `api/products/`. It shows all the data but not the filter button.

Comment: I added an image on my post so you can see that category value 2 is existing and the filter seems not working. Thank you @ArakkalAbu

Comment: Can you add your model?

Comment: Already added the model and serializers

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: @Marin already followed the docs. I have no idea what I missed. I followed the instructions on installing django-filter and used djangFilterBackend globally.

Comment: Up ___________ please someone help I am stuck with this

Comment: Try: api/products/?category=2

Maybe you have appending slash?

Comment: @Marin I already tried that, it dosnt work, it return all the products. On tutorials that I watched, once they add the filterset_fields, the filter button on browsable will show up, in my case it doesnt show and the filter is not working.

Comment: @SadDeveloper I'm having the same problem but with function based views, have you figured out how to solve this problem?

Comment: @OliverHnat on my situation, I was pointing to a different file location.

Answer (score 0):

The filter button is a part of the [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module, and is **NOT** built-in to the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module.

##### Installation for the `django-crispy-forms` module:

1. Run `pip install django-crispy-forms`
2. Add `'crispy_forms',` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file

If installed correctly with proper use of the django-filter module, the "Filters" button should now show up on your browsable API page.

[image: Browsable API page with filters button after installing django-crispy-forms]

Answer (score 0):

I came into the same question today and it took me a while to make it display. We don't need to install the crispy-forms. The filter button will display when we define the filterset_fields here. Tutorial defines it as filterset_fields = (...) not [...]. But even if I changed my code to ['sku', 'name'] it still works. Reference: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html

```html
class ProductView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
   
    # filterset_class = [ProductFilter]
    filterset_fields = ('sku', 'name')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXrVu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRu3S.png)